# Managing old passwords in Keepass2

Tags: keepass

In Keepass 2, is there a history or some place that it can remember old passwords? I would like to have a record of previous passwords that are used if I change a password for a given account. Is there a plugin that could do this? I would like this feature for organizational purposes.

Comment: I wonder: When asking this question, wasn't there a "History" tab for each password entry? Also: https://keepass.info/help/v2/entry.html#hst

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This option should be enabled by default, go to History tab of each entry.

You can also control it in Database Settings - Advanced tab, automatic entry history maintenance.

Click on "view" button below after selecting one entry to view it, including it's old password.

[image: KeePass History tab] [image: KeePass's Adv]

Comment: ok but it doesn't actually say what the old password was?

Comment: @Celeritas Click on "view" button below after selecting one entry to view it, including old password.